# Would this predicate work ? this came on my quiz to find the position of element X in a data structure called list

Tags: list, data-structures, recursion, prolog

example:
        position(1,list(1,list(2,nil)),Z).
        Z = 1.
        position(3,list(1,list(2,list(3,nil)),Z).
        Z = 3.
      where Z is the position of element X in a data structure of a list in the above     format

Here was my solution:

```
      position(X,list(nil),0).                %empty list
      position(X,list(X,T),1).                %list with X as head or first element 
      position(X,list(H,T),Z):-
                             position(X,list(T,nil),Z1), %X is in tail of list (H,T)
                             Z is Z1 + 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't work.
The correct predicate is:

```
position(X,list(nil),0).                %empty list
position(X,list(X,T),1).                %list with X as head or first element
position(X,list(H,T),Z):-
                position(X, T, Z1), %X is in tail of list (H,T)
                Z is Z1 + 1.
```

Writing `position(X,list(T,nil),Z1), %X is in tail of list (H,T)` will result in a loop, and it is a logic error as there is no reason to call `position` with a `list(T, nil)`. `T` is already either a list or the `nil` atom.

Comment: yes ofCourse makes sense error in logic but isn't this equivalent to position(X,[],0).
position(X,[X|T],1).
position(X,[H,T],Z):- position(X,T,Z1), Z is Z1 + 1. for the predefined list structure in prolog. @andreapier